# Process only specific properties from the Azure CosmosDB to Kafka topic using CosmosDB-Source-Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-cosmosdb, apache-kafka-connect

Our requirement is to pull data from the Azure CosmosDB and send it to the Kafka topic with only some specific properties in JSON format using CosmosDB source connect.

We have done the setup as given in the below article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/kafka-connector-source

So currently records from the Azure Cosmos DB are published to Kafka topic properly.

Now how we can send only some of the properties to the Kafka topic? 
Sample data in the Azure Cosmos DB:

```json
    {
      "Address": "string",
      "Company": "string",
      "Country": "string",
      "Email": "login9@example.com",
      "Login": "login9",
      "Name": "string",
      "Password": "login9#login",
      "Telephone": "string",
      "id": "f1b0bf30-51e7-468e-ac09-39f471490a4a",
    }
```

Expected Value in Kafka topic:

```json
    {      
      "Email": "login9@example.com",
      "Login": "login9",
      "Name": "string",
      "id": "f1b0bf30-51e7-468e-ac09-39f471490a4a",
    }
```

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/kafka-connect-cosmosdb/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/kafka/connect/source/CosmosDBSourceTask.java#L190), you should find the information you're looking for.

To me, seems like they just pass the whole database record over to the Kafka Connect SourceRecord list.

You can use other stream-processing tools like Kafka Streams / ksqlDB to select a subset of fields and write to other topics. You can also try using [Kafka Connect transforms to drop/blacklist certain fields](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html).